# JQuery Mobile not displaying framework graphics properly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning JQuery and trying to get it working with ASP.NET MVC 4. I can't seem to get it to show properly in mobile browser. Home button, List View, Buttons.. etc...
Why would it be showing like this?

[image]

Code of my master Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css")" />*@

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <a href="@Url.Content("~")" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
            @Html.Label("Hello World")

            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            @*@RenderSection("featured", false)*@
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Thank you</h1>
        @Html.Partial("_ViewSwitcher")
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it broken in other mobile browsers too or just opera?

Comment: Also, what's in the Site.Mobile.css file?

Comment: Site.Mobile.css doesn't exist yet therefore it commented out. I just put a reference in there for when I'll have the file in the future.

Comment: And this is how it appears in all browsers.

Comment: Try setting `<!DOCTYPE html>` on line 1 for HTML5.

Comment: Its set. Wasn't included in the code above, I'll update it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
"jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" file has to be referenced, not the mobile.theme one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `~/` before `Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.min.css` on line 6. Is that what you intended?

Comment: You're right I was but it's not it. I guess I missed it while I was trying different things/ troubleshooting. I also tried simply dragging/dropping files from the Solution Explorer which gave me "../../Content/jquery/..." paths.
Didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: I have a feeling your javascript files aren't being properly referenced. Make sure it's looking at your file tree correctly. Usually you wouldn't use `~` at all in these cases. A beginning `/` generally means the root of the project directory.